# output some but not all php encode JSON data in a table

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this variable from php that I am turning to JSON by

```
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($json_array) ?>;
```

And the output format is something like this when I get a console log:

```
0:
Carat: "0.70"
Clarity: "VVS2"
Color: "D"
Cut: "Very Good"
Polish: "Fair"
Price: "2806"
Product ID: "17"
Product Name: "0.7 Carat Cushion Diamond"
Report: "IGI"
Shape: "Cushion"
Symmetry: "Ideal"
purl: "http://klaussongs.com/product/0-7-carat-cushion-diamond/"
__proto__: Object
1: {Product ID: "19", Product Name: "0.9 Carat Round Diamond", Carat: "0.90", Clarity: "VS2", Shape: "Round", …}
2: {Product ID: "21", Product Name: "1 Carat Radiant Diamond", Carat: "1.00", Clarity: "SI1", Shape: "Radiant", …}
```

The problem is I am using objects.key to get carat, clarity, cut and so on but instead the keys are 0, 1, 2, before the objects: How can I change the following code to only generate my table with some of those keys such as (carat, clarity, price etc) removing some that I don't want such as product ID and generate the table. Right now when I generate the table the headings are 0, 1, 2, 3 which is the JSON var parent keys, but I want to select (not all) but some of the child keys. 
All helps are appreciated.

```
      function generateTableHead(table, data) {
      let thead = table.createTHead();
      let row = thead.insertRow();
      for (let key of data) {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        let text = document.createTextNode(key);
        th.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(th);
      }
    }

    function generateTable(table, data) {
      for (let element of data) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        for (key in element) {
          let cell = row.insertCell();
          let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
          cell.appendChild(text);
        }
      }
    }


    let table = document.querySelector("#simpleTable");


    let data = Object.keys(myData);


    // create selected tbody as values
    generateTable(table, myData);


    // create selected thead as keys 
    generateTableHead(table, data);
```

Comment: `myData` is an array, it's keys are the indexes. The table headings are `Object.keys(myData[0])`

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that, Thanks. Could you please advice on the loop part as well, how can I remove one column like product ID from myData in that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array containing the properties you want to show, instead of going through all the columns.

```js
const myColumns = ["Carat", "Clarity", "Color"];

function generateTable(table, data, columns) {
  for (let element of data) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in columns) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
    let th = document.createElement("th");
    let text = document.createTextNode(key);
    th.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(th);
  }
}

generateTable(table, myData, myColumns);
generateTableHead(table, myColumns);
```